# Close Quick Panel (window.show_quick_panel) on key release in Sublime Text

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am new to sublime text plugin development, I am developing a plugin that involves opening a quick panel on pressing certain key binding. I want the panel to be open only as long as the keys are pressed and once the keys are released I want it (Quick panel) to close. I've figured out I can fire the 'hide_pannel' command to close my Quick panel but I want it to fire on release of the key combination.

For example lets say, I want the quick panel on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and I want it to close after I release <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

So I was thinking if I fire 'hide_pannel' command after release <kbd>ctrl</kbd> should do the trick, but I couldn't find how I can fire a certain command on key release instead of key press. If there is any other solution or workaround other than what I was thinking please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can detect when a key is pressed in Sublime, you can't directly detect when it has been released. Similarly, the `modifier` keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, etc) can not be mapped to anything on their own and always require a non-modifier as well. For example, <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> is allowed, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> alone is not.

That said, theoretically it's possible to interface with the underlying operating system using a `python` library that uses native code in your plugin to observe the state of the keyboard.

I'm not aware of any Sublime specific examples of doing such a thing, however. Note also that in doing this you would also have to provide such a library for all of the platforms that Sublime supports (Windows, MacOS, Linux, and 32 or 64 bit versions on Windows/Linux), presuming that you want your plugin to work on multiple platforms.